# simple insert query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

My query :

```
INSERT INTO media (id,name,path,module,page,created)
    VALUES ('1','slider1.jpg','user\img\slider\','user','home','1534933852')
```

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

```
Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 125)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'user','home','1534933852')' at line 1

Comment: You need to escape backslashes

Comment: \'  changes its property in query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the backslashes.  These are escape characters in MySQL.  So you can double them up:

```
INSERT INTO media (id,name,path,module,page,created)
    VALUES ('1', 'slider1.jpg', 'user\\img\\slider\\', 'user', 'home', '1534933852');
```

If you are passing the values in from an application, then use parameters and you will not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  ... that was the right answer ... i did figure it out already and continued on with my work , and then forgot to close the thread. Thanks for helping tho. :)